# How to upload with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to upload a photo but I can't.

I looked for `//input[@type='file']` and I didn't find it, I tried the ID also without success.

just below the lines of code that I tried to upload without success

```
elmFoto = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
elmFoto.send_keys(r"C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Imagens\image.PNG")

elmFoto = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Carregar do desktop')]")
elmFoto.send_keys(r"C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Imagens\image.PNG")
```

[image]

Comment: You say you tried, but didn't share any code. Show us what you thought would work and explain how you could tell it didn't. Also, note that there's no `<input>` tag in the bit of html you highlighted. If you provide a link to the actual page this is on in addition to your code, people might be able to provide some other hints.

Comment: I also have doubts about this, must there necessarily be an INPUT tag for the upload to be possible?

Comment: @Grismar Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider suggesting OP to update the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: No, if the website works, there's clearly no need for an `<input>` tag, but you still need to replicate the behaviour of the page as if a user was using it. I pointed it out because your XPath expression looks for an input, and it will never find one there.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I see no reason why you're telling me to do so in the comments, feel free to do so yourself, only to get told that copying an pasting from a console in a browser, or from an actual web page would not be helpful, and this is actually a good example where an image *is* more helpful. From the screenshots, it's perfectly clear why the code won't  work, and OP already added that code.

Comment: @Felipe please include a section of code that can actually be run, so we can see what the value of `driver` would be when you run that code. It's entirely possible your mistake is in earlier lines of the code. Also, you did not mention what page you're actually loading - if it's public, please share the URL.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium your comments are unhelpful and directed at a comment that had no mistake - please take this line of conversation elsewhere.

Comment: @Grismar The page I'm using for automation is not public, unfortunately.
I will take into account your comments and review the complete code.

Comment: Please do, have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (I'm not coming up with this stuff myself, this page has many helpful hints on how to maximise you chances of getting an answer, and writing a question that's useful to others as well)

Answer (score 1):

You Can also try with the Robot class for uploading the file.

```
    Robot rob=new Robot();
    StringSelection str=new StringSelection(FileLocation);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(str, null);
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
 
    // release Contol+V for pasting
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
 
    // for pressing and releasing Enter
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```